# Moq + Unit Testing - System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq, ivalueconverter

I'm tring to use a lambda with a multiple-params function but Moq throws this exception at runtime when I attempt to call the `mock.Object.Convert(value, null, null, null);` line.

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch
```

The code is:

```
var mock = new Mock<IValueConverter>();

mock.Setup(conv => conv.Convert(It.IsAny<Object>(), It.IsAny<Type>(),
    It.IsAny<Object>(), It.IsAny<CultureInfo>())).Returns((Int32 num) => num + 5);

var value = 5;
var expected = 10;
var actual = mock.Object.Convert(value, null, null, null);
```

What is the proper way to implement it?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It's your `Returns` clause.  You have a 4 parameter method that you're setting up, but you're only using a 1 parameter lambda.  I ran the following without issue:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IValueConverter()
{
    var myStub = new Mock<IValueConverter>();
    myStub.Setup(conv => conv.Convert(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Type>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<CultureInfo>())).
        Returns((object one, Type two, object three, CultureInfo four) => (int)one + 5);

    var value = 5;
    var expected = 10;

    var actual = myStub.Object.Convert(value, null, null, null);

    Assert.AreEqual<int>(expected, (int) actual);
}
```

No exceptions, test passed.

Comment: I was going to inquire as to whether this was a test of the framework or not, but I figured I'd give the benefit of the doubt that perhaps it was interim code to try getting the Mock to behave properly.

Comment: I assume it is too, but it made me chuckle anyway.

Comment: I hear ya.  When I executed the code, I thought "yup, framework libraries still working." :)

Answer (score 8):

Not an answer for OP but perhaps for future googlers:

I had a `Callback` that didn't match the signature of the method being setup

```
Mock
    .Setup(r => r.GetNextCustomerNumber(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(AccountCounter++)
    .Callback<string, int>(badStringParam, leadingDigit =>
    {
        // Doing stuff here, note that the 'GetNextCustomerNumber' signature is a single int 
        // but the callback unreasonably expects an additional string parameter.
    });
```

This was the result of some refactoring and the refactoring tool of course couldn't realise that the `Callback` signature was incorrect

Comment: wow, I was banging my head against this same issue and get kept glossing right over the callback until I read your post. Hugely helpful and I'm glad you posted it.

Comment: This was my issue as well.  I added a parameter to a method, fixed the Setup() call, but missed the Callback() parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because you are passing `null` but `It.IsAny<Object>()` is expecting any `object` except `null`?  What happens if you do the following?:

```
var actual = mock.Object.Convert(value, new object(), typeof(object), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This is just a stab in the dark from me, I'm more familiar with Rhino.Mocks.

---

My 2nd guess:

Having looked at the Moq.chm that comes with the download,

You are using the `Setup(Expression<Action<T>>)` method which "Specifies a setup on the mocked type for a call to a `void` method."

You want te `Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<T,TResult>>)` method that "Specifies a setup on the mocked type for a call to a value returning method".

So you could try:

```
mock.Setup<Int32>(
    conv => {
        conv.Convert(
            It.IsAny<Object>(), 
            It.IsAny<Type>(),
            It.IsAny<Object>(), 
            It.IsAny<CultureInfo>());
        return  num + 5;
        });
```

Comment: mock.Setup<TResult> infers the return type as Object because the Convert method returns an Object.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I thought that the type in `Returns<>` is the output type, but in fact it was the input type(s).

So if you have a method

```
public virtual string Foo(int a, int b) { ... }
```

The correct clause is `.Returns<int, int>(...)`, NOT `.Returns<string>(...)` which is what I thought initially.

My mistake was because I was testing a function with the same input and return type initially - for example `public virtual string Foo(string a)`.