# Why does Moq throw TargetParameterCount exception

Tags: moq

Does anyone have any idea why I get this exception trying to mock my account controller login method?

Here is the moq code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Validate_User()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IAccountService> mockAccountService = new Mock<IAccountService>();

    mockAccountService.Setup(m => m.Login(It.Is<string>(userName => userName == "Samuel"),
                                          It.Is<string>(password => password == "password")))
                                          .Returns<bool>(b => true);

    AccountController target = new AccountController(mockAccountService.Object);

    // Act
    RedirectResult result1 = (RedirectResult)target.Login("Samuel", "password");
    //RedirectResult result2 = (RedirectResult)target.Login("RK", "password");
    //RedirectResult result3 = (RedirectResult)target.Login("Tatiana", "password");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result1, "~/DashBoard/Cases");
    //Assert.AreEqual(result2, "~/DashBoard/Cases");
    //Assert.AreEqual(result3, "~/DashBoard/Cases");
}
```

In my AccountController/Login action it crashes on this line:

```
bool loginValid = _accountService.Login(userName, password);
```

And `_accountService` is set with DI with a `IAccountService` instance, a mock.object.

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    bool Login(string userName, string password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7715103/1768744), I think that the Return part of your Setup method, should have the same signature of the method of interface:

```
mockAccountService.Setup(m => m.Login(It.Is<string>(userName => userName == "Samuel"),
                                          It.Is<string>(password => password == "password")))
                                          .Returns<bool>((u,p) => true);
```