# Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks - MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor, moq

So I have a unit test which uses a method in a class called `ImpositionCalculatorManager`. In this class I use dependency injection so I can access the methods on another class called `ImpositionCalculatorRepository`.

The `ImpositionCalculatorManager` looks like this:

```
 public class ImpositionCalculatorManager : IImpositionCalculatorManager {
        private readonly IImpositionCalculatorRepository _impositionCalculatorRepository;
        public ImpositionCalculatorManager(IImpositionCalculatorRepository impositionCalculatorRepository) {
            _impositionCalculatorRepository = impositionCalculatorRepository;
        }
        public ComboBoxItem[] ReturnInkDataSource() {
            return _impositionCalculatorRepository.ReturnInkDataSource();
        }

        public ComboBoxItem[] ReturnCoatingDataSource() {
            return _impositionCalculatorRepository.ReturnCoatingDataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

In my unit test I mock the `ImpositionCalculatorManager` and pass in a mocked version `ImpositionCalculatorRepository` into the constructor for the manager class.

However I get the error `Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks`.

This is what my unit test fixture looks like:

```
 public class ImpositionCalculatorPresenterTestFixture {
        private ImpositionCalculatorPresenter _impositionCalculatorPresenter;
        private readonly SystemVariablesPresenter _systemVariablesPresenter;
        private readonly Mock<IImpositionCalculatorManager> _mockImpositionCalculatorManager;
        private readonly Mock<ISystemVariablesView> _mockSystemVariablesView;
        private readonly Mock<IPrintingDesignManager> _mockPrintingDesignManager;
        private readonly Mock<ISystemVariablesManager> _mockSystemVariablesManager;
        private readonly Mock<IImpositionCalculatorRepository> _mockImpositionCalculatorRepo;
        private Mock<IImpositionFormView> _mockView;

        public ImpositionCalculatorPresenterTestFixture() {
            _mockImpositionCalculatorRepo = new Mock<IImpositionCalculatorRepository>();
//Error occurs on the below line
            _mockImpositionCalculatorManager = new Mock<IImpositionCalculatorManager>(_mockImpositionCalculatorRepo.Object);
            _mockSystemVariablesView = new Mock<ISystemVariablesView>();
            _mockPrintingDesignManager = new Mock<IPrintingDesignManager>();
            _mockSystemVariablesManager = new Mock<ISystemVariablesManager>();
            _systemVariablesPresenter = new SystemVariablesPresenter(_mockSystemVariablesView.Object, _mockSystemVariablesManager.Object);
        }

 [TestMethod]
        public void PopulateInkDataSources_ApplicationOnLoad_InkDataSourcesPopulatedWithDataFromJSON() {
            //Arrange
            SetupImpostionPresenter();
            _mockView.SetupProperty(r => r.InkSideOneDataSource);
            _mockView.SetupProperty(r => r.InkSideTwoDataSource);
            _mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Setup(r => r.ReturnInkDataSource())
                .Returns<ComboBoxItem[]>
                (x => new ComboBoxItem[] {
                        new ComboBoxItem("Test", 1 ),
                        new ComboBoxItem("Test 2", 2)
                });

            //Act
            _mockView.Raise(r => r.FormOnLoad += null, new EventArgs());

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(_mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Object.ReturnInkDataSource()
                == _mockView.Object.InkSideOneDataSource && _mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Object.ReturnInkDataSource()
                == _mockView.Object.InkSideTwoDataSource
                );
        }

private void SetupImpostionPresenter() {
            _mockView = new Mock<IImpositionFormView>();
            _impositionCalculatorPresenter = new ImpositionCalculatorPresenter(_mockView.Object,
            _mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Object, _mockSystemVariablesManager.Object, _systemVariablesPresenter,
            _mockPrintingDesignManager.Object);
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked on stack overflow and people are saying that it's because an interface doesn't have a constructor and only the class does and that I shouldn't have to pass anything into the constructor but when I remove the constructor arguments from the mock, I receive the error `Parameter count mismatch` when trying to setup a method from the manager.

I would just like to mock the manager so I can setup a method to return the values which I have already set.

Why will this not work?

Comment: Looks like you are missing Mock declaration here 
`private readonly Mock<IImpositionCalculatorPresenter> _impositionCalculatorPresenter;`

Comment: My presenter isn't an interface and I would have to make all my methods virtual and I don't want to do this. Would doing this make a difference anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I reproduced your `Parameter count mismatch` problem.  Try these two changes:

1) (as previously discussed) create your manager without any constructor and without any other dependencies; and

2) fix the `Func` given to the `ReturnInkDataSource` mock: change this:

```
    _mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Setup(r => r.ReturnInkDataSource())
            .Returns<ComboBoxItem[]>
            (x => new ComboBoxItem[] {
                    new ComboBoxItem("Test", 1 ),
                    new ComboBoxItem("Test 2", 2)
            });
```

to

```
    _mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Setup(r => r.ReturnInkDataSource())
            .Returns(
                () => new ComboBoxItem[] {
                        new ComboBoxItem("Test", 1 ),
                        new ComboBoxItem("Test 2", 2)
                      }
              );
```

First change is foundational DI/mocking -- we don't need mocks for mocks.

Second change is `Moq` specific -- it's necessary because the params for the lambda given to `Returns()` must match the params provided in `Setup()` -- see [Moq + Unit Testing - System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714551/moq-unit-testing-system-reflection-targetparametercountexception-parameter)

Comment: Ahh, I understand. The parameter count mismatch issue wasn't to do with the repository at all. It was that I mocked my `ReturnInkDataSource` to accept a `ComboBoxItem[]` and I didn't pass one in. Thank you for staying committed. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to test the concrete `ImpositionCalculatorPresenter` implementation?  I'm also assuming that this `ImpositionCalculatorPresenter` implementation is expected to respond to a `FormOnLoad` event.

If my assumptions are correct, then your `_mockImpositionCalculatorManager.Setup(r => r.ReturnInkDataSource()).Returns<ComboBoxItem[]> (...))` should be sufficient and would not require a backing `IImpositionCalculatorRepository` mock or impl or anything -- your goal of "I would just like to mock the manager" seems to be handled by this moq setup, which fakes the guts of the manager which the `ImpositionCalculatorPresenter` needs.

Comment: I am trying to test the concrete `ImpositionCalculatorPresenter` and yes the presenter responds to the `FormOnLoad` event. I also would've thought that my implementation was correct. The manager method calls the repository to attempt to return data.

Comment: The manager method `ReturnInkDataSource()` appears to be mocked correctly, no need to involve the repository at all.

Comment: sorry meant to be more detailed.

I'd expect that when you change manager mock to just `_mockImpositionCalculatorManager = new Mock<IImpositionCalculatorManager>();`, then it would compile. If you make this change then what error do you get?

Comment: once I do this and it calls the method in the manager it throws the exception  'Parameter count mismatch'