# Parameter count mismatch Exception when mocking HttpClient in F#

Tags: f#, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to mock the .NET HttpClient with Moq in F#. I currently have the following code:

```
open System.Net.Http
open Foq

[<Fact>]
let ``Some test`` () =
    Mock<HttpClient>.With
        (fun client ->
            <@ client.GetStringAsync("foo")
                --> task { return "bar" } @>)
    |> ignore
```

Upon running the test I get the following error.

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.

How can I fix this?

I know there are many similar questions, but they are all for C#. They mention that either there are arguments missing somewhere or [something with a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732660/6329629) should be added. But I can't figure out what arguments are missing, or how to add the callback to my example.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a bit and it seems to be caused by an underlying problem with F# quotations, rather something that can be addressed within Foq. For example, the following code throws the same unhandled exception:

```ml
<@ task { return "bar" } @>
    |> FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation
    |> printfn "%A"
```

I reported this as [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12669) in the F# core repository.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and the bug report!